# X Window System error on Ubuntu - BadWindow > (invalid Window parameter) when using IntelliJ

Tags: java

I am having trouble running a java program on Ubuntu 10.04 desktop with jdk1.6.0_24.  The application works fine on windows platform and starts up fine in Linux, it just crashes with the following error when I close an input dialog.  This only happens when running the application from IntelliJ and not when it is run from the Terminal as a built jar.

> The program 'Time Clock' received an X Window System error.
>   This probably reflects a bug in the program. The error was 'BadWindow
>   (invalid Window parameter)'.   (Details: serial 693 error_code 3
>   request_code 20 minor_code 0)   (Note to programmers: normally, X
>   errors are reported asynchronously;    that is, you will receive the
>   error a while after causing it.    To debug your program, run it with
>   the --sync command line    option to change this behavior. You can
>   then get a meaningful    backtrace from your debugger if you break on
>   the gdk_x_error() function.)

I've been looking for fixes, but haven't found anything useful yet.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: jdk1.6.0_24 is not the newest.  Does the error happen in the newest too?

Comment: I also tried with java-6-sun-1.6.0.26 that comes on Ubuntu.

Comment: ,,,just tried jdk1.6.0_29 too, no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get the application to run using sun jdk1.6.0_22.